# How to debug TLS negotiation failure with load-balancer?

Tags: android, ssl

I have an Android app which communicates to a backend server via HTTP POST requests.  I would like to upgrade it to HTTPS.  The API I'm using is HttpLib.postRequest.

I'm finding that a direct connection to my Apache server works fine.  But a connection via a load balancer doesn't work.  My load balancer is from Aliyun.  I've tried two different load balancers, both fail the same way.  The direct symptom is that I get an "unknown_err" on the phone.

I can capture traffic with tcpdump, which proves that it's connecting to the correct place and attempting to negotiate.  The session ends with the client sending an HTTPS error "Certificate Unknown (46)".

Normally this is caused by bad certificates or configuration.  But I know that my certificates are all valid.  Other browsers work fine connecting to the same server to load normal web pages.  And the iOS version of the same app also works fine.  Browsing to the web site on an Android phone works fine even when the app is failing to connect.  The website is https://zaomengshe.com so you can check the certificate there.  I also have a different setup with a load balancer and a certificate from Let's Encrypt.

I guess there is some peculiarity of Aliyun's load balancers and Android that's preventing a successful negotiation.  Perhaps I need to enable support for some algorithm or key size or something.  I did read that TLS 1.2 wasn't supported until API version 20, so I updated the minimum supported version to 20.  That didn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [report by SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=zaomengshe.com) for this domain clearly says:

> This server's certificate chain is incomplete. Grade capped to B.

The reason for this problem is probably a messed up configuration at the load balancer: only the leaf certificate is served inside the TLS handshake but not the intermediate certificates needed to build the trust chain. Desktop browser usually try to work around such broken configurations but other applications usually don't.

This means that this is very likely the reason your application fails. And the issue need to be fixed at the load balancer by also configuring the intermediate certificates.

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense, thanks.  Thanks a lot for the pointer to SSLLabs!